# Annotation and Pointcut on same class method

Tags: spring, aspect

I have two aspects but only TryCatchLog is working even when method annotated with CatchRedBanner.

1. One on all methods returning AssertionData in package pageActions

```
package com.abc.acceptance.b2b.aspects;

@Aspect
@Component
public class TryCatchLogAspect {

    @Pointcut(
            "execution(com.abc.acceptance.b2b.annotations.AssertionData com.abc.acceptance.b2b.pageActions..*(..))")
    private void pageActionsTryCatchLog() {
    }

    @Around("pageActionsTryCatchLog()")
    public Object tryCatchLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable { ...
```

2. This one for methods with my annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CheckRedBanner {
}

-----

package com.abc.acceptance.b2b.annotations;

@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CheckRedBannerAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(CheckRedBanner)")
    public void myAdviceForMethodAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        handleBeforeExecution(joinPoint);
    }

    protected void handleBeforeExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Made iitttt !!! ");
    }
}
```

My code is calling only TryCatchLog but not CheckRedBanner even when I annotate the method

```
package com.abc.acceptance.b2b.pageActions;

@Component
@Slf4j
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
public class BroadbandPanelActions extends PageActions {

    @CheckRedBanner
    public AssertionData clickFindAddress() {
        broadbandPanel.getFindAddressButton().click();
        return new AssertionData();
    }
...
```

Comment: By any chance `CheckRedBannerAspect ` within package `com.abc.acceptance.b2b.annotations` is not picked up / auto-detected by ComponentScan ? The code should otherwise work without any issues

Comment: I have @ComponentScan({"com.abc.acceptance.b2b"}) so I think should be okay. If I add my annotation to any method in other class e.g. in package com.abc.acceptance.b2b.pageActions then CheckRedBanner is called.

Comment: Is there any restriction or conflict on having both class and annotation?

Comment: Please read regarding [advice ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) and I can only reproduce the behaviour you have mentioned when I am not explicitly calling `proceedingjoinpoint.proceed()` from `@Around` advice . Please share the `@Around` advice logic or please add `proceedingjoinpoint.proceed()` to the method . I am pretty sure that is the case here

Comment: Just tried and CheckRedBanner is not executed even when i have commented out TryCatchLog aspect code.

Comment: Please check my answer and see if it helps. If not , please update the question with the entire `ryCatchLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)` logic

Comment: Just noticed the last comment from you . If the aspect cannot execute individually , that need to be sorted out first .

Answer (score 0):

From the reference docs regarding [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)

> When two pieces of advice defined in different aspects both need to
>   run at the same join point, unless you specify otherwise, the order of
>   execution is undefined. You can control the order of execution by
>   specifying precedence.

For me the behaviour is reproducible when I order the Aspects as follows . I have ordered so that `Around` advice is executed before `Before` advice . Also note that I have commented the `joinPoint.proceed();` call.

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(0)
public class TryCatchLogAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(sec2.aop.bean.AssertionData sec2.aop.bean..*(..))")
    private void pageActionsTryCatchLog() {
    }

    @Around("pageActionsTryCatchLog()")
    public Object tryCatchLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

         // Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

        System.out.println("pageActionsTryCatchLog");
        return new AssertionData();
    }

}
```

and

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class CheckRedBannerAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(CheckRedBanner)")

    public void myAdviceForMethodAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        handleBeforeExecution(joinPoint);
    }

    protected void handleBeforeExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Made iitttt !!! ");
    }
}
```

when I uncomment the `proceed()` call both the aspects work.

```
@Around("pageActionsTryCatchLog()")
public Object tryCatchLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

    System.out.println("pageActionsTryCatchLog");
    return new AssertionData();
}
```

When we are not explicitly calling `joinPoint.proceed();` spring does that for us. But in the first case we are returning without calling the underlying method and the `@Before` advice fails to execute.

Comment: I think for any class with @Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE) its not working.

Comment: will it be possible for you to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?